# Hold and release CUPS print jobs from command line

Tags: command-line, cups

Is is possible to hold and release CUPS print jobs from command line? How to do it?

I tried [cupsenable](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.5/man-cupsenable.html):

```
sudo cupsenable --release myprinter
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out by myself:

do

```
lpq
```

to get the job id and then

```
lp -i job-id -H resume
```

See [this page](http://www.it.uu.se/datordrift/maskinpark/skrivare/cups/) for a reference. See also [this one](http://www.ehow.com/how_10034588_resume-printing-ubuntu-cups.html).

Comment: Debian: I didn't have lpq by default, but lpstat showed the job numbers.