# View all user's printing jobs from the command line

Tags: command-line, fedora, printing, cups

I'm running Fedora 17, Gnome (3?), and using bash from terminal.  Whenever I run `lpstat` I only get a list of my jobs, but every time I go to retrieve my jobs from the printer, somebody else is printing and mine hasn't even started!  What gives?

I want to view a list of all users' jobs, not just mine.

I tried `lpq` to no avail.  I've also tried `lpstat -t` and same result -- just my jobs, not anyone else's.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lpstat -u all` (as root) should show all users and all jobs that are currently queued:

```
-u <logon-IDs>
```

Prints the status of output requests for users, in which  can be one or all of the following:

- `<user>` - A user on the local system, as in `lpstat -u user`
- `<host!user>` - A user on a system, as in `lpstat -u systema!user`
- `<host!all>` - All users on a particular system, as in `lpstat- u systema!all`
- `<all!user>` - A particular user on all systems, as in `lpstat -u all!user`
- `all` - All users on all systems specified, as in `lpstat -u all`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I've been in the hospital for a while.
@charlesbridge - Thanks for your response -- I believe that is the solution I was looking for!  Unfortunately, I am not longer working at that contract and am unable to test it.

Comment: I'm trying this while logged into the actual CUPS server and it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying `lpstat -u all` and get nothing. But if I grep through the `/var/spool/cups/*` directory for usernames I'm finding them.

Comment: The command only shows currently queued jobs, not the history of jobs.  I've updated the answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me but the following method did. However, if you have a directory that contains your LPD control files, typically it's /var/spool/cups`, you'll notice a bunch of control files in there. These files are kept as a result of the`MaxJobs` setting, which defaults to 500 when unset.

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/spool/cups/ | wc -l
502
```

#### Another source of usernames?

If you look through these files you'll notice that they contain usernames, and not just ones for accounts that are present on the system.

```
$ strings /var/spool/cups/* | grep -A 1 job-originating-user-name | head -5
job-originating-user-name
tammyB
--
job-originating-user-name
tammyB
```

So we could select all the entries that contain the username followed by the B.

```
$ sudo strings /var/spool/cups/* | grep -A 1 job-originating-user-name | \
    grep -oP '.*(?=B)' | sort -u
ethan
guest-AO22e7
root
sam
saml
slm
tammy
```

This list can then be adapted in the same way as we were originally using to take the list of users from `getent passwd`, like so:

```
$ sudo lpstat -W completed -u $(strings /var/spool/cups/* | \
    grep -A 1 job-originating-user-name | \
    grep -oP '.*(?=B)' |sort -u | paste -sd ',') 
mfc-8480dn-1525         tammy           545792   Thu 28 Nov 2013 01:36:59 PM EST
mfc-8480dn-1526         saml            699392   Sat 30 Nov 2013 10:34:34 AM EST
mfc-8480dn-1652         root              1024   Tue 28 Jan 2014 01:19:34 AM EST
mfc-8480dn-1672         saml              1024   Sun 09 Feb 2014 01:56:26 PM EST
```

#### References

- [why is /var/spool/cups so huge?](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2011-February/392448.html)

Comment: On a SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 box I'm working on there are users with jobs in the queue with suffixes of "I" and "B". I couldn't work out what these suffixes mean but the following command accepts them all. Also some lines had spaces in. The slightly modified command which worked for me is `lpstat -W not-completed -u $(strings /var/spool/cups/* | grep -A 1 job-originating-user-name | grep -oP '.*(?=B|I)' | sort -u | paste -sd ',' | tr -d [:space:])`

Answer (score 2):

While `lpstat -u all` didn't work on my system, i could see other users' jobs when specifying `-u` without any value:

```
lpstat -u
```

Comment: Anyone know how to restart a particular job after listing the jobs on the system?

Comment: Got the answer from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48448/hold-and-release-cups-print-jobs-from-command-line?rq=1.  Just need to type `lp -i <job-id> -H resume`