# How to show the CUPS printer jobs history?

Tags: cups, lpr

I am printing some files from a remote computer to a network printer with the lpr command.
It apparently worked, but some minutes later when I typed lpstat or lpq, the job had already disappeared, it had probably already printed the file.
Is there a way to check the history or the log of my successfully completed jobs in the printer queue?

Comment: Of course I have no access to the printer right now, and therefore I cannot check if the file was printed or not.

Comment: Via the web interface it is easy.

Comment: What is that, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: http://localhost:631/.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes a program exists: `lpstat` - print cups status information

```sh
$ lpstat -W completed
```

> ```
> -W which-jobs
>      Specifies which jobs to  show,  completed  or  not-completed  (the
>      default).  This option must appear before the -o option and/or any
>      printer names, otherwise the default (not-completed) value will be
>      used in the request to the scheduler.
> ```

Or if you prefer via the following *web pages*:

```
https://localhost:631/printers/[NameOfPrinter]?which_jobs=completed
http://localhost:631/jobs?which_jobs=completed
```

Kind regards

Comment: This will only show the completed for your userid. You can give a list of users like this: `lpstat -W completed -u user1,user2`.

Comment: Does lpstat have a rolling window for the completed print job history, or does it show all jobs that were ever completed?

Answer (score 10):

The other answer when tried produced the following:

```
$ sudo lpstat -W completed
mfc-8480dn-1652         root              1024   Tue 28 Jan 2014 01:19:34 AM EST
```

Adding a user, `saml` gives you that user's history:

```
$ sudo lpstat -W completed -u saml | head -2
mfc-8480dn-1524         saml             23552   Thu 28 Nov 2013 10:45:44 AM EST
mfc-8480dn-1526         saml            699392   Sat 30 Nov 2013 10:34:34 AM EST
```

But the `-u all` mentioned in this U&L Q&A titled: [View all user's printing jobs from the command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63388/view-all-users-printing-jobs-from-the-command-line) did nothing for me.

```
$ sudo lpstat -W completed -u all | head -2
$
```

Curiously I could do this:

```
$ sudo lpstat -W completed -u saml,root | head -3
mfc-8480dn-1524         saml             23552   Thu 28 Nov 2013 10:45:44 AM EST
mfc-8480dn-1526         saml            699392   Sat 30 Nov 2013 10:34:34 AM EST
mfc-8480dn-1652         root              1024   Tue 28 Jan 2014 01:19:34 AM EST
```

So one hackish way to do this would be to formalize a list of the users on your system and then add that as a subcommand to the `-u` argument like so:

```
$ sudo lpstat -W completed -u $(getent passwd | \
    awk -F: '{print $1}' | paste -sd ',')
```

Just to show that this sees all the users locally you can get a unique list of your users like so:

```
$ sudo lpstat -W completed -u $(getent passwd | \
    awk -F: '{print $1}' | paste -sd ',') | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u
ethan
root
sam
tammy
```

#### Issues?

One problem with this is if the user printing to CUPS does not have an account locally then they won't get displayed.

But if you have a directory that contains your LPD control files, typically it's /var/spool/cups`, you'll notice a bunch of control files in there. These files are kept as a result of the`MaxJobs` setting, which defaults to 500 when unset.

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/spool/cups/ | wc -l
502
```

#### Another source of usernames?

If you look through these files you'll notice that they contain usernames, and not just ones for accounts that are present on the system.

```
$ strings /var/spool/cups/* | grep -A 1 job-originating-user-name | head -5
job-originating-user-name
tammyB
--
job-originating-user-name
tammyB
```

So we could select all the entries that contain the username followed by the B.

```
$ sudo strings /var/spool/cups/* | grep -A 1 job-originating-user-name | \
    grep -oP '.*(?=B)' | sort -u
ethan
guest-AO22e7
root
sam
saml
slm
tammy
```

This list can then be adapted in the same way as we were originally using to take the list of users from `getent passwd`, like so:

```
$ sudo lpstat -W completed -u $(strings /var/spool/cups/* | \
    grep -A 1 job-originating-user-name | \
    grep -oP '.*(?=B)' |sort -u | paste -sd ',') 
mfc-8480dn-1525         tammy           545792   Thu 28 Nov 2013 01:36:59 PM EST
mfc-8480dn-1526         saml            699392   Sat 30 Nov 2013 10:34:34 AM EST
mfc-8480dn-1652         root              1024   Tue 28 Jan 2014 01:19:34 AM EST
mfc-8480dn-1672         saml              1024   Sun 09 Feb 2014 01:56:26 PM EST
```

#### References

- [why is /var/spool/cups so huge?](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2011-February/392448.html)

Comment: Don pass usernames after `-u` and it returns all jobs of all users.

Answer (score 7):

I think `/var/log/cups/page_log` etc. has the history of completed jobs.

An alternative is the web interface

```
http://localhost:631/
```

which also shows completed jobs. I'm not sure where the web interface gets its information from.

Answer (score 4):

Every answer above seems to be only interested in *completed* jobs...

What if you are also interested in jobs which were *canceled* by the user or an admin? What if you want to know how many jobs were *aborted* by the print system itself, due to driver or other problems?

For these cases use:

```
lpstat -W all -o
```

Also, you may want to know more details about each job. In this case add `-l` for a long output format:

```
lpstat -l -W all -o
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see jobs of other users, than for some reason specifying `-u` without value works (at least on my system):

```
lpstat -W completed -u
```

Answer (score -3):

This command appears to clear history as well as any active jobs:

```
sudo cancel -a -x
```